# CS50 pset4 filter blur function turns the whole image to one color

Tags: c, pixel, cs50, gaussianblur

The blur function is the implementation of a box blur algorithm that works by taking each pixel and, for each color value, giving it a new value by averaging the color values of neighboring pixels. Trying to understand this problem took me a whole day and a lot of frustration. I am not sure why the image does not blur but changes the whole to one color.

```
// Blur image
    void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
    
      RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float count = 0;
            float red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;
    
           // for row-1,row,row+1
           //for col-1,col.col+1
    
            for(int r = -1; r <= 2; r++)
            {
                for (int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
                {
                    if(r >= 0 && r < height && c >= 0 && c < width)
                    {
                        red +=   temp[r][c].rgbtRed;
                        green += temp[r][c].rgbtGreen;
                        blue +=  temp[r][c].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
    
             image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red/count);
             image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green/count);
             image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue/count);
    
    
    
        }
    
    }
    
    
     return;
    
    }
```

Comment: Using loops to scan the surrounding pixels is a good idea, but the way you have it now those values are always the same. What you want is `for(int r = i - 1; r <= i + 1; r++)` and the same with `c` except with `j` instead of `i`. You also don't need the else clause with continue. There's no code after it to skip.

Comment: r and c takes only -1, 0 and 1 (which is the index before a pixel, the pixel itself and the index after the pixel), if  I  wrote r = i - 1 , if i = 10 then 10 -1 = 9 which should not happen again , since r takes only -1, 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I did not add i th and j th index to the row(r) and column(c) while calculating red, green and blue where I was not able to move to neighbouring rows and columns.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

  RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
    }
}


for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        float count = 0;
        float red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;

       // for row-1,row,row+1
       //for col-1,col.col+1

        for(int r = -1; r <= 2; r++)
        {
            for (int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
            {
                if(r >= 0 && r < height && c >= 0 && c < width)
                {
                    red += temp[i+r][j+c].rgbtRed;
                    green += temp[i+r][j+c].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += temp[i+r][j+c].rgbtBlue;
                    count++;
                }
               
            }
        }

         image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red/count);
         image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green/count);
         image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue/count);



    }

}


 return;

}
```

Comment: `<= 2` in the loop condition for `r` is incorrect and `if(r >= 0 && r < height && c >= 0 && c < width)` doesn't check if the final position will be out of bounds, it just skips all of the `- 1` values. `for(int r = i - 1; r <= i + 1; r++)` and `for(int c = j - 1; c <= j + 1; c++)` would fix both of those.

Comment: `r` should be  `< 2`. Sorry for the typo and `If (r >= 0 && r < height && c >= 0 && c < width)` should be corrected to  `if( r + i >= 0 && r + i < height && c + j  >= 0 && c + j  < width)` or like what you mentioned `for(int r = i - 1; r <= i + 1; r++)` and `for(int c = j - 1; c <= j + 1; c++)`. I figured that out later. Turns out you were right. But both will work fine. Thanks!

Comment: But I tried coding it according to what you mentioned, I am getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: so I changed `if(r >= 0 && r < height && c >= 0 && c < width)` to `if(r+i >= 0 && r+i < height && c+j >= 0 && c+j < width)`  but the blurred image is become a smaller version of the image to the top left corner and the leftover part is filled in black color